# Can I programmatically include an argument in a bash script?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I have a bash script that uses ffmpeg inside it. I want to be able to pass *my* script a parameter that, if set, adds a parameter to the ffmpeg command inside my script.

At it's most basic, this is what I'm trying to do:

```
ffmpeg \
# if duration flag is set for my script #
-t $DURATION \
# end if #
-rest of ffmpeg parameters...
```

I know I could wrap the whole thing in an `if`, but the ffmpeg command has a lot of other parameters that would then need to be kept updated in two places.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an array to store the dynamic parameters:

```
if [ some test ]
then
   args+=(-t "$DURATION")
fi

ffmpeg "${args[@]}" -rest of ffmpeg parameters...
```

You could also use an unquoted variable instead of an array in this case, but that wouldn't hadle arguments with whitespace or glob characters.

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
-t $DURATION \
```

by

```
$([[ -n "$DURATION" ]] && echo -- "-t $DURATION") \
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks like what I'm after, but just so that I understand it, what is happening here? I haven't seen the double square brackets, -n or echo -- before (very new to bash)

Comment: `[[ ... ]]`: Returns a status of true or false depending on the evaluation of the conditional expression `-n "$DURATION"`. `-n STRING` returns true if string is not empty. See: `help [[` and `help test`